# How to append all the files of a subfolder in stata

Tags: directory, append, global, stata

I work from two computers, a desktop and a laptop,
so usually my code goes like this:

```
global laptop "laptop/pathToFolder"
global desktop "desktop/pathToFolder"

cd $laptop

* make some awesome calculations and fill two folders out of data files
```

Now suppose I have my two folders with dta files, and I want to `append` them such that I make one big dataset.

This code works: I took it from [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1530135-append-all-dta-files-in-directory)

```
frame create coeftab_t
frame change coeftab_t
cd ".\results\coefplots\bonferroni\data\2\"
local theFiles: dir . files "*.dta"
append using `theFiles'

cd $laptop
cd ".\results\coefplots\bonferroni\data\4\"
local theFiles: dir . files "*.dta"
append using `theFiles'
cd $laptop
```

After `append`ing the first folder I want to move to the next folder, so I have to get back to the previous working directory which was `$laptop` and then change again. (I just want to change it at the top of my script.)

So I lost some hours with chat gpt trying this:

```
frame create coeftab_t
frame change coeftab_t
local theFiles: dir ".\results\coefplots\bonferroni\data\2\" files "*.dta"
append using `theFiles'
* here the error pops up

local theFiles: dir ".\results\coefplots\bonferroni\data\4\" files "*.dta"
append using `theFiles'
```

and the error I get is:

```
file file_one_fakename.dta not found
```

but there are no typos or specific file names in the path to the subfolder.

How can I make the second attempt to work? I don't want to change the working directory multiple times in the script just because I have to use another PC.

Comment: Please post a minimal reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2):

You can set a local to be something different depending on what computer you use like this. Since I do not have a access to your folder and files I do not know if this is the exact solution to the issue you are having in your code. But this answers the general question I think you are asking.

```
* Test what username current computer uses
di "c(username)"

* Set root path depending on what computer you are using
if "c(username)" == "MyLaptop" {
    global path "C:\Users\MyLaptop\myproject\"
}
if "c(username)" == "MyDesktop" {
    global path "C:\Users\MyDesktop\myproject\"
}


cd ".\results\coefplots\bonferroni\data\2\"
local theFiles: dir . files "*.dta"
append using `theFiles'

cd $path
cd ".\results\coefplots\bonferroni\data\4\"
local theFiles: dir . files "*.dta"
append using `theFiles'
```